# Arduino bluetooth sends web address to IOS/Android on connecting

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, arduino

I've been searching online and unfortunately haven't been able to find out how to do it or if it is even possible.

Here is the process I'm attempting:

1. Android/iPhone user sees a bluetooth signal on their phone (coming from the Arduino)
2. User connects their phone to that bluetooth signal
3. Upon connecting (with no other action from the user and without having the user install an app), the Arduino sends a web address to the connected phone **(Is this possible? and if so, can someone point me to a reference?)**
4. Either the phone automatically opens the default browser and loads the web page from the address that was sent, or the user gets a prompt/dialog indicating that data was received and asks the user what to do with it
5. User completes a form on the web page which then sends data back to the Arduino via the bluetooth. (**Would also like to know if this is possible?)**

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a number of questions, but broadly the answer to what you are asking is "no".

You will need an app on the phone to interact with your Bluetooth peripheral (Arduino).